# How to prevent event on Angular Material stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper

I am using material stepper on a Angular 8 project. I need to attach a button to each step, but I don't want to change the step each time the user clicks the button. So, how can I disable the stepper navigation only when click the button within? Thank you all in advance.

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyrcdf-vmo5nm

[image: Picture of the stepper]

Answer (score 2):

Finnaly solved!

I implemented the `event.stopPropagation()` on the function binded to stepper buttons.

**Template**:

```
<ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address
    <div class="status-icon" (click)="clickButton($event)">
    <button>Do something 2</button>
  </div>
 </ng-template>
```

**Component:**

```
clickButton(event: any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('You clicked on a button');
   }
```

**Stackblitz with full example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyrcdf-vmo5nm